# Open the selected file(s) in the web browser

Tags: netbeans

Using Netbeans, I fail to find the option for opening a given file in a web browser (preferrably in a standalone instance - not embedded into NB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [QuickOpener](https://github.com/kinkadzs/QuickOpener-NetBeans) plugin. You can customize commands to open the file with anything you want.

Comment: It works nicely. It doesn't integrate with web projects though (e.g. one typically doesn't want to open a .html file directly - but through localhost)